# ladder plot code modification

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot ladder plot as described on this page: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/6252-Ladder-plot

Can this code be modified to show mean and standard error bars also on either side of plot? Alternatively, box plots for both columns could be shown on the same plot. Some code for standard error bars is available on this page: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60767/how-to-display-error-bars-for-cross-over-paired-experiments

Thanks for your help.

Edited:
Sample paired data is given below:

```
paired_df = structure(list(X0 = c(9, 13, 13, 13, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
+ 40, 42, 43, 44), X0.1 = c(10, 40, 45, 46, 36, 37, 38, 40, 46, 
+ 45, 46, 43, 44, 46)), .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, 
+ 14L), class = "data.frame")
    A  B
1   9 10
2  13 40
3  13 45
4  13 46
5  35 36
6  36 37
7  37 38
8  38 40
9  39 46
10 40 45
11 40 46
12 42 43
13 43 44
14 44 46
```

Comment: SO doesn't want me to put "what have you tried?" in a comment, but that's what I would really like to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand (although many people do not) that boxplots show neither means nor standard deviations and they don't display the interquartile range except by accident. You could use the same strategy to "annotate a boxplot". (Using the data construction of the prior question.)

```
x<-data.frame(A=c(1:10), B=c(1:10)+rnorm(10))
xx<-stack(x) # restructures data for stripchart function

with( xx, boxplot(values~ind))
apply(x,1,lines, col="blue")
apply(x,1,points, col="red")
```

[image]

This could probably be improved for more general use by using smaller points and having the colors be transparent, if there were large numbers of cases.

Comment: Thanks. This is good. I can add notches to boxplot to show more information by using option "notch=TRUE".

Answer (score 3):

Here are a two leads for you:

1. To create a ladder plot, the easiest way is to use the `ladderplot` function from the `plotrix` package. Code example:

> ```
> # install.packages('plotrix')  ## this is to install the plotrix package
> require('plotrix')
> ladderplot(my.2.columns.matrix)
> ```

.
 2. To overlay error bars, the easiest way is to use the `errbar` function from the `Hmisc` package. Code example:

> ```
> # install.packages('Hmisc')  ## this is to install the Hmisc package
> require('Hmisc')
> errbar(c(1,2),c(mean1, mean2),c(mean1-sem1,mean2-sem2),c(mean1+sem1,mean2+sem2),add=TRUE)
> ```

Try to adjust these pieces of code to make them work for you, and comment if you are stuck somewhere.

## edited to add a full example:

See a full code example, and the resulting picture:

```
require('plotrix')
require('Hmisc')

vals = cbind(rnorm(5,mean=3,sd=1), rnorm(5,mean=5,sd=1))

ladderplot(vals)

means = colMeans(vals)
sems = apply(vals, 2, function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))

errbar(c(1,2),c(means[1], means[2]),c(means[1]-sems[1],means[2]-sems[2]),c(means[1]+sems[1],means[2]+sems[2]),
       add=TRUE,
       errbar.col='red',col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Only if the error bars could be put a little outside main points (a little left for V1 and a little right for V2) as they will not be seen if there are many points. Maybe we can make 2 more variables "meanV1" and "meanV2", and plot error bar there. This code will be very useful.